# How to sum a column, created by counting IDs and grouping by on multiple coulmns?

Tags: sql, databricks

In the raw table temp.raw_data, running below query provides

**Query**

```
select post_evar8, MY, count(distinct visit_id) as uv
from temp.raw_data
where MY >= 202110 and MY <= 202112 
group by post_evar8, MY;
```

**Results:**

[image: Example output from query 1]

**When I create an aggregate table on the raw data and then run the above query I get much higher counts**

**Creating Aggregate Table Using Raw Table Data **

```
create table temp.xy as 
select MY, ID, count(distinct visit_id) as uv, pages, post_evar10, post_evar205, post_evar8, post_evar5
from temp.raw_data
group by MY, ID, pages, post_evar10, post_evar205, post_evar8, post_evar5;
```

When I run the same query I ran on the raw data on the aggregate table where I sum the count colums created in table temp.xy, I get below results which is much higher than the actual counts:

**Query**

```
select post_evar8, MY, sum(uv) as uv
from temp.xy_data
where MY >= 202110 and MY <= 202112 
group by post_evar8, MY;
```

[image: Example output from query 2]

I know I am doing something wrong in the way I am grouping by, but I am not sure how to fix it, any direction or help will be much appreciated. Ultimately I want to push this data into Tableau, that is why I need to create the aggregate table, since the raw table is big.

Comment: It looks like you forgot the `where` filter in the 2nd query. Does that explain the difference?

Comment: @shadowtalker: second query is where I am creating the aggregate table on the raw data, the third query is the filter query on the aggregate table.

Comment: The issue is that UV (Unique Visits) is not an additive metric that can be rolled up from your aggregate to (post_evar8, MY) level because it's double counted.

Comment: @JHH: Yes I also thought so but what is a work way to fix it or approach this issue so I dont get double counts.

Comment: Try `SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: @NewCode "Unique Count" metrics are not additive. You need to design aggregates for different granularity. The base table needs to have a "visit_id" column, so that you can aggregate to any level. These types of metrics are usually expensive to compute: unique visits, unique visitors, unique users...etc.